# split produces uninitialised values

Tags: regex, perl, split

I just trying to split a string on the basis of pattern. The following code I tried but it produces some uninitialized elements. Can anybody explain whats happening here?

```
my $string = 'this is the string which is going to be splitted';

my $pattern = qr/(\bis\b)|(\bthe\b)/;

my @splitted = split(/$pattern/,$string);

print join "\n#", @splitted;
```

Output

```
Use of uninitialized value $splitted[2] in join or string at D:/Testing/Context/split_un.pl line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $splitted[4] in join or string at D:/Testing/Context/split_un.pl line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $splitted[8] in join or string at D:/Testing/Context/split_un.pl line 9.
this 
#is
#
# 
#
#the
# string which 
#is
#
# going to be splitted
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html - look at the end of that page, the part about capturing groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When split regex uses capturing groups it passes captured delimiter together with splited elements, and some of them were undefined.

Depending on what you want this regex wont produce undefined elements,

```
my $pattern = qr/(\bis\b|\bthe\b)/;
```